# Flutter App keep on crashing and increase in memory usage

Tags: memory-leaks, heap-memory

I have made a game using flutter which have multiple pages for different levels but when I reload or play the next level it keep on increasing the ram usage (each levels has some assets images) is the assets images are stored in in cache memory or what ? But dispose has been used in each page still the ram usage keeps on increasing

I already tried to minimize the resolution of image but it still using a lot memory

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.